# Execute async loaded Javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm working on a single page app, every time I click a link e.g., the event is stopped, and request to `template.php` with the parameters of the link. (A link with `href="www.site.com/login"` would request to `template.php?path=login`)

But there is javascript in my login page, and currently it's added to the body in a script tag, but it's never executed.

Is there any way to execute asynchronously loaded javascript like in the example above?

Comment: How much debugging have you done? Have you looked in the dev tools console/network tabs to see if there are any errors?

Comment: If you add a `<script>` tag to the DOM, the code should be executed. It will be synchronous unless you give it the `async` attribute.

Comment: Note that scripts are not executed if the tag is assigned using `innerHTML`. You need to use `document.createElement("script")`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I added the javascript using `innerHTML`. After I tried it using `document.createElement("script")` it worked